# deployment, IN BOUND DATA SET ERROR

Tags: deployment, change-set

I have few changes to be made from one sand box to another, when i do that i am getting quick action error in inbound data sets when i validate, but now the problem is now the source destination is refreshed and i cannot go back to see the dependencies for the error.Is there any way to leave that one item and continue with deployment?

Answer (score 0):

No thats not possible. unless you have any other backup you can't make change in change set or Salesforce doesn't allow you to deplly only selected files.